# view query performance scenarios

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a view named AllUsers which returns a result set of data for all users in a system.  Let's say that the underlying query is somewhat complex.

Let's say that I need the ability to get a user by ID. All of the attributes should be returned for the single user as is returned for the full user set.

I'm assuming that SQL Server is smart enough to optimize performance when I apply a where clause to a view so that it optimizes the query as a single record query as opposed to selecting all records and then filtering the records based on the single ID provided in the where clause.  Can you please confirm this?

Comment: Yes, it does the smart thing.

Comment: explain should show the optimizer at work

Comment: Look at the execution plan. It will show you what is happening. It is far more accurate about what the engine is doing than asking random people on the internet

Comment: It depends.  If the query plan for the view is cached, it might read the entire data set.  If the view is merged with the outer query, then indexes can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You must insert a Where clause at the end of Select sentence. Example:

```
Select id, name, department
from AllUsers
Where id = 1
```

The optimization depends wether the AllUsers table have or not an index defined with the id column inner.

[image]

If the Id Column is not defined in a index SQL Server will try to scan in the whole table seeking your record.